# Calculator with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am a beginner and trying to write a simple Calculator in Javascript but something is wrong.

When the user enters numbers, "Number 1" and "Number 2", then the following should occur for addition, subtraction, multiply and division (for example):

```
Number1 = 5, Number2 = 3
then   => 5 + 3 = 8,
          5 - 3 = 2,
          5 * 3 = 15,
          5 / 3 = 1.6
```

When the user gives numbers to specific equation, then displays the result of these operations.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Function Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function show_cal(){
    function num(){
    a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
    c=a+b;
    document.form1.result1.value=c;

    a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
    c=a-b;
    document.form1.result2.value=c;

    a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
    c=a*b;
    document.form1.result3.value=c;

    a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
    c=a/b;
    document.form1.result4.value=c;
    }

    function addition(){
    a=Number(document.form1.num3.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num4.value); 
    c=a+b;
    document.form1.result1.value=c;
    }

    function subtraction(){
    a=Number(document.form1.num5.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num6.value); 
    c=a-b;
    document.form1.result2.value=c;
    }

    function multiply(){
    a=Number(document.form1.num7.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num8.value); 
    c=a*b;
    document.form1.result3.value=c;
    }

    function division(){
    a=Number(document.form1.num9.value);  
    b=Number(document.form1.num10.value); 
    c=a/b;
    document.form1.result4.value=c;
    }

    /*function formValidator(){
    var number = document.getElementById('number');
        if(isNumeric(number, "Only Numbers pls")){
        return true;
        }return false;
    }

    function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){ //gia keno
        if(elem.value.length == 0){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
        }
    return true;
    }

    function show_clear(){
        document.form1.display.value=null;
        num1= null;
        num2 = null;
        lastaction= null;
        action = null;
    } */
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="400" align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
    <form name="form1" action="">

    <tr align="center">
    <td width="600" height="112" align="center" border="1">
        <h1 align="center"> Calculator </h1>
    Number 1: <input name="num1" type="text" size=10/>
    Number 2: <input name="num2" type="text" size=10/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
    <td width="500">
    <input name="num3" type="text" size=10/> + 
    <input name="num4" type="text" size=10/> =
    <input name="result1" type="text" size=10/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <br/>
    <tr align="center">
    <td width="500">
    <input name="num5" type="text" size=10/> -
    <input name="num6" type="text" size=10/> =
    <input name="result2" type="text" size=10/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <br/>
    <tr align="center">
    <td width="500">
    <input name="num7" type="text" size=10/> *
    <input name="num8" type="text" size=10/> =
    <input name="result3" type="text" size=10/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <br/>
    <tr align="center">
    <td width="500">
    <input name="num9" type="text" size=10/> /
    <input name="num10" type="text"size=10/> =
    <input name="result4" type="text" size=10/>
    </td>
    </tr>


        <br/>
    <td height="13"></tr>
    <tr align="center" width="100">
    <td>
    <input name="result" type="button" onClick="show_cal()" value="Result" />
    <input type="button" onClick="show_clear()" value="Clear"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try something like JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/Na4MK/ , this will help others understand what is going wrong (the answer should quickly follow once I click on "Add Comment")

Comment: You're not calling any function. show_cal() just define your functions.

Comment: This question is oddly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099652/javascript-calculator

Comment: @RocketHazmat Maybe it's homework for the same teacher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is you have a function **sum** within a function **show_calc** and you don't call this function.
You need call the function num when finish the showcalc function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function show_cal(){

    function num(){
      a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
      c=a+b;
      document.form1.result1.value=c;

      a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
      c=a-b;
      document.form1.result2.value=c;

      a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
      c=a*b;
      document.form1.result3.value=c;

      a=Number(document.form1.num1.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num2.value); 
      c=a/b;
      document.form1.result4.value=c;
    }

    function addition(){
      a=Number(document.form1.num3.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num4.value); 
      c=a+b;
      document.form1.result1.value=c;
    }

    function subtraction(){
      a=Number(document.form1.num5.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num6.value); 
      c=a-b;
      document.form1.result2.value=c;
    }

    function multiply(){
      a=Number(document.form1.num7.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num8.value); 
      c=a*b;
      document.form1.result3.value=c;
    }

    function division(){
      a=Number(document.form1.num9.value);  
      b=Number(document.form1.num10.value); 
      c=a/b;
      document.form1.result4.value=c;
    }

    num();
}
```

But I better ways to make this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code could be cleaner and violates DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) repeatedly.

Try this:

```
<form action="javascript:void(null);" method="post" onSubmit="calculate(this);">
    <p><label>Number 1: <input type="number" /></label></p>
    <p><label>Number 2: <input type="number" /></label></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></p>
    <p>N1 + N2 = <span>-</span></p>
    <p>N1 - N2 = <span>-</span></p>
    <p>N1 * N2 = <span>-</span></p>
    <p>N1 / N2 = <span>-</span></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(form) {
        var fc = form.children,
            n1 = parseInt(fc[0].children[0].children[0].value || 0,10),
            n2 = parseInt(fc[1].children[0].children[0].value || 0,10);
        fc[3].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue = n1+n2;
        fc[4].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue = n1-n2;
        fc[5].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue = n1*n2;
        fc[6].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue = n1/n2;
    }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wkR7N/)

Comment: Why `parseInt`? I'd think `parseFloat` or `+(num)` even better for the wide range of possible numbers inputted

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css">
<script src="./calc.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div id="textBox1">
             <input type="text"id="textBox" placeholder="0"/>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('1')" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('2')" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('3')" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('4')" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('5')" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('6')" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('7')" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('8')" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('9')" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('0')" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('+')" value="+">+</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('-')" value="-">-</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('*')" value="*">*</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('/')" value="/">/</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('%')" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="clr()" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="disPlay('.')" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons" onclick="backSpace()" value="B">B</button>
        <button class="calc-buttons-equal" onclick="result()" value="=">=</button>
        </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
calc.js:---
var res = "";
function disPlay(x) {
  nan = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
  if (nan === "NaN" || nan === "Infinity" || nan ===  "undefined" || nan === "-Infinity") {   // delete Nan,infinity,undefined after entering the numbers.
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";
  }
  if (res && (x >= 0 || x <= 0)) {
    res = false;
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";
    document.getElementById("textBox").value += x;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("textBox").value += x;
    res = false;
    var y = [];
    y = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    p = y.length;
    if ((y[p - 2] === "*" || y[p - 2] === "/" || y[p - 2] === "%" || y[p - 2] === "+" || y[p - 2] === "-" || y[p - 2] === ".") && (x === "*" || x === "/" || x === "%" || x === "+" || x === "-" || x === ".")) {
      document.getElementById("textBox").value = y.slice(0, p - 1);

    }

  }
}

function clr() {
  document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";
}

function backSpace() {
  bakSpa = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
  if (bakSpa === "NaN" || bakSpa === "Infinity" || bakSpa === "undefined" || bakSpa === "-Infinity") {
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";
  } else {
    var value = document.getElementById("textBox").value;`enter code here`
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
  }

}

function result() {
  exp = "";
  exp = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
  l = exp.length;
  if (exp[0] == '*' || exp[0] == '/' || exp[0] == '%' || exp[0] == '+' || exp[l - 1] == '+' || exp[l - 1] == '%' || exp[l - 1] == '/' || exp[l - 1] == '*' || exp[l - 1] == '-') {
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = 'NaN';
  } else {
    exp = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    res = eval(exp);
    console.log(res);
    document.getElementById("textBox").value = res;
    if(res===undefined){
      document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";
    }
  }
}
cal.css:-
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
::placeholder { 
    color: red;
    opacity: 1; 
  }

body {
background: #F6F6F6;
}
.calculator   {
max-width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 2px solid #111;
border-radius: 5px;
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex: 0 1 60%;
min-width:400px;
color: #F6F6F6;
}
#calc-buttons ,.calc-buttons {
background-color: gray;
border: none;
color: white;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-top: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-flex;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
width:125px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
.calc-buttons-equal{
    background-color:orange;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 190px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:388px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    }
#textBox1 input   {
background: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #111;
color: #333;
text-align: right;
font-size: 40px;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some details by explaining how you answer the question [Read how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I created an api to make a calculator automatically, just put the api inside script tag (<script src="https://calculatorapi.netlify.app/api.js>"). I created this api to help more people build their own web apps. If you want to style my api calculator just do:

```
<style>

<!--To result input-->

input[type="text"] {

<!--Your style-->

}

<!-- To Calculator buttons e.g: 1,2,3 -->

input[type="buttons"] {

<!-- Your style -->

}
</style>
```

Comment: This would be a much better example if you used a snippet to actually create an example using your referenced library.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
              z="";  
             fun =""
             ans="";
            function dis(val) 
            { 
                ans = document.getElementById("result").value;
               if (ans === "Infinity" ||ans === "-Infinity" || ans ===  "undefined") {  
                 document.getElementById("result").value = "";
                }
                if(z&& (val >= 0 || val <= 0)){
                    z = false;
                document.getElementById("result").value="";
                document.getElementById("result").value+=val;
                
                }
                else{
                ans = document.getElementById("result").value+=val;
                z = false;
                 var y = [];
                 y = document.getElementById("result").value;
                 p = y.length;
                if ((y[p - 2] ==="*" ||y[p - 2] ==="/" ||y[p - 2] ==="%" ||y[p - 2] ==="+" ||y[p - 2] ==="-" ||y[p - 2] ===".") && (val ==="*" ||val ==="/" ||val ==="%" ||val ==="+" ||val ==="-" ||val ===".")) {
                 document.getElementById("result").value = y.slice(0, p - 2)+y[p-1];

                }
                }
            } 
            function solve() 
            { 
                let i,j;
                i= ans;
                 j=i[i.length-1];
                if(i[0]==="*"||i[0]=="/"||i[0]==="%"||i[0]==="+"){ 
                 document.getElementById("result").value = undefined;
                
                }
               
                else if(j==="*"||j==="/"||j==="%"||j==="."||j==="+"||j==="-"){
                    document.getElementById("result").value = undefined;
                }
              
                else {
                    z="";
                    let x = document.getElementById("result").value; 
                     z = eval(x);
                     if(z===undefined)
                     {
                    document.getElementById("result").value = "";
                     }
                     else{
                        document.getElementById("result").value = z;
                     }
                
            }  
            } 
            function clr() 
            { 
                document.getElementById("result").value ="" 
            } 
            function back() 
              { 
                 var i = document.getElementById("result").value;
                 if(i==="undefined"||i==="infinity"||i==="-infinity"){
                    document.getElementById("result").value ="";
                 }
                 else{
                 document.getElementById("result").value = i.substr(0, i.length - 1);
                 }
                
                 } 
        </script>
        <style>
         * {
             background-color: black;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
             margin: 0px;
             text-align: center;
             box-sizing: border-box;
            
            
         }
         .disply{
               height: 30%;
               width: 100%;
               box-sizing: border-box;
   
         }
         .functions{
             height: 68%;
             width: 100%;
             box-sizing: border-box;
             
            

         }
        
        input{
             background-color:black; 
              border:whitesmoke;
             color: white;
             text-align: center;
             font-size: 45px;
             cursor: pointer;
             height: 20%;
             width: 24.2%;
            
             }
             button{
             background-color:lightslategray; 
             color: white;
             text-align: center;
             font-size: 90px;
             cursor: pointer;
             height: 18%;
             width: 24%;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 50%;
             }
             button[type=button4]{
                width: 48.4%;
                padding-right: 24.2%;            
                border-radius: 40%;
             }
             button[type=button2]{
                 background-color: orange;
                 font-size: 60px;
             }
             button[type=button1]{
                 background-color: whitesmoke;
                 color: black;
                 font-size: 60px;
             }
             input[type=text]{
                height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
               background-color:black;
               text-align: right;
               color: white;
               font-size: 100px;
              
             }
             ::placeholder{
                 color: bisque;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="disply">
            <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="0"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="functions">
            <button type="button1" value="AC" onclick="clr()">AC</button>
            <button type="button1"value="/" onclick="dis('/')">/</button>
            <button type="button1"value="%" onclick="dis('%')">%</button>
            <button type="button2"value="back" onclick="back()">back</button>
            <button type="button3"value="7" onclick="dis('7')">7</button>
            <button type="button3"value="8" onclick="dis('8')">8</button>
            <button type="button3"value="9" onclick="dis('9')">9</button>
            <button type="button2"value="*" onclick="dis('*')">*</button>
            <button type="button3"value="4" onclick="dis('4')">4</button>
            <button type="button3"value="5" onclick="dis('5')">5</button>
            <button type="button3"value="6" onclick="dis('6')">6</button>
            <button type="button2"value="-" onclick="dis('-')">-</button>
            <button type="button3"value="1" onclick="dis('1')">1</button>
            <button type="button3"value="2" onclick="dis('2')">2</button>
            <button type="button3"value="3" onclick="dis('3')">3</button>
            <button type="button2"value="+" onclick="dis('+')">+</button>
            <button type="button4"value="0" onclick="dis('0')">0</button>
            <button type="button3"value="." onclick="dis('.')">.</button>
            <button type="button2"value="=" onclick="solve()">=</button>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some details by explaining how you answer the question [Read how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).